# ProGuard remove variable annotation in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have annotation CatalogSync

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CatalogSync
```

also I have constructor like this

```
internal class Repository @Inject constructor(
    @CatalogSync private val userCatalog: UserCatalog,
    @CatalogSync private val priceCatalog: PriceCatalog,
    @CatalogSync private val carsCatalog: CarsCatalog,
    ...
```

and tried to find all variables annotation with ‘CatalogSync'

```
var count = 0
for (member in this::class.memberProperties) {
    if (member.annotations.any { it is CatalogSync }) {
        count += 1
    }
}
```

But this code works when minifyEnabled is disabled.

I tried to use such rules, but they didn't work.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class kotlin.annotation.*
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.company.test.CatalogSync
-keep @com.company.test.CatalogSync class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.company.test.CatalogSync *;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.